# Change SVN username due to a typo

Tags: svn

I inherited an SVN server a while ago and I noticed in my `authz` file that one of my users had had his username created with a typo in it. He wants me to change it but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. The SVN server has been around for a few years, so he's made commits to the repository.

My initial thought was to just go ahead and delete his user from the `authz` file, re-create the user using

```
htpasswd -md /path/to/repo/authz UserName
```

Then change all commits performed by his old user to the new one. There's 2 problems with this though:

1. This is a production server and I have no test environment
2. I'll use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263568/change-author-of-old-commits-in-subversion) to change his username on old commits but see 1.

Is this the only option I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can touch nothing in password-file for changing username in existing SVN-commits, new username will be needed only for new commits
2. Answers (borrible's and asmit's) in linked question are full and correct and cover all details (used command and importance of editing `pre-revprop-change` hook **before** editing author of commit)
3. Don't worry - successful or unsuccessful `propset` doesn't broke repository, because they are only permitted legal methods of interaction with repo in your case
4. You can easy build test-environment locally with `file:///`-accessible repository and some commits in it

PS: do not forget to remind the user to delete the old credentials in his SVN, otherwise cached credentials will be used with expected "Authorisation failed"