# Changing SVN author/username name | ubuntu

Tags: svn, ubuntu

Whenever i commit the code in SVN repository, it shows that the code is commit by user "SVN" instead of my own username "some_name".

It looks that i need to change or update the username/author on my machine(client side). Can anybody tell me that how i can change this?

Here is the detail of SVN INFO

```
 svn info
Path: .
URL: svn+ssh://**************
Repository Root: svn+ssh:*******************
Repository UUID: ******************
Revision: 123456
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: svn
Last Changed Rev: 121345
Last Changed Date: 2012-11-08 07:08:37 +0500 (Thu, 08 Nov 2012)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671662/svn-change-username

Comment: Well, masking URL was wrong. Blindly I can recommend only verify, under which user started SVN (svnserver, if I'll write details) on server and under which user you *really login*

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - sorry, you clearly miss question

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: yes you are right, its exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Securing Svnserve using SSH](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html), "Testing SSH with TortoiseSVN" chapter (even if you don't use TSVN) contain all answers

---

Additional HowTos:

- [Setting Up Subversion (SVN) with SSH (svn+ssh)](http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-up-svn)
- [svn+ssh Setup Mini-tutorial](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2004-03/0253.shtml)

Comment: Hi @LazyBadger: Thanks for your answer, sorry i was late in responding. The solution was the same which Rody provided in comment. I was exactly looking for that but perhaps couldnt convey my thougths well in question.

Comment: You may provide the the same link in answer below. Because on that link, im  not convinced the way he has asked question.